# Pass property as function argument and convert it name to string inside

Tags: c#, reflection, nameof

I would like to be able to pass any possible type as function parameter.

Now, there is problem with passing property eg.

```
class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to use:
nameof(Foo.Bar)
but I'm unable to do A(Foo.Bar) where in A will be used nameof.

I want to have sure that string is created from property and I would like to have property passed to API and do nameof inside API.

Is there any possibility to pass property through function to nameof? I would like to hide converting of property to string inside of my class instead of getting ready string. How achieve that?

edit: The clue is about:

```
class B
{
    public Prop {get; set;}
}

void foo([?])
{
    Console.WriteLine(nameof([?]));
}
```

What put instead [?] to have console output like: Prop.

Comment: Why not pass a `string` and use `nameof` at the calling site?  Also you do realize that `nameof(T)` is just going to give you the literal string "T" no matter what type you pass right?

Comment: Sorry, wrong example, this is something how I like it to work. I need many usages of string so the call will by ugly. I want to hide nameof inside my api, to be sure that string is created from real property not a dummy data

Comment: Maybe update your question accordingly and explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please stop using Foo as an example. Try use real-world examples.

Answer (score 2):

The c# compiler uses 'nameof' to kind of find and replace things at compile time, so it won't work how you expect it to. Instead you'll need to get the names of the properties at run-time using either Expressions or Reflection.
Here's an example of how to do it using Expressions:

```
public static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        var member = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return member.Member.Name;
    }
    public static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (body == null)
        {
            body = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
        }

        return body.Member.Name;
    }

    public static void PrintName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(GetName(expression));
    }

    public static void PrintName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(GetName(expression));
    }
```

Used like this:

```
class B
{
    public Prop {get; set;}
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        PrintName<B>((b) => b.Prop); 

        //Or
        var someObject = new B();
        PrintName(() => someObject.Prop); 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interpreting `nameof` a little bit wrong here.

In your first example the method will always print `T` and does not depend on the type of `T`. The `nameof` keyword does nothing other than replacing the expression given to it by a string representation of the expression. e.g. we are giving `nameof` the parameter `T` and he will return the string representation of that expression: `T`.

```
void A<T>(T smth)
{
   Console.Writeline(nameof(T)); // example usage
}
```

In general the usage of `nameof` is to provide refactor-able method/property/... names to methods.

For example the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` has as parameter the name of the argument that is *out of range*.

```
void Test(int value)
{
    if (value < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
    // yada yada
}
```

If we provide the name as hardcoded string as in the example above we would get an inconsistency when renaming the parameter.

In order to solve this we use `nameof` and because we are providing the parameter itself instead of a hardcoded string it is refactor safe.

```
void Test(int value)
{
    if (value < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));
    // yada yada
}
```

Comment: I know where can I use nameof, I wonder how to use it inside function for passed argument. I'm making some reflection stuff and I need to compare properties names. I can make that user of API will use everywhere nameof(prop) but I would like to have this inside API to have sure that string is created from real property

Comment: @senfen There is no way to ensure that the user is giving you correct input and you should expect that he is giving you *incorrect* inputs. Just check if the specified property exists instead of trying to enforce providing a 'correct' property name.

Comment: Ok, but it also looks bad if function call have tones of nameof, its unreadable. So, there is no possibility to achieve that ?